# Last letter in input needs to be in red color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got requirement in my project it says if the user is typing some thing on input field  last typed character should be in red color 
as follows

[image]

i have tried nth-child and all, no thing is working

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You really can't do that, there's no way to change the color of individual characters. There are workarounds, like overlaying a second input, using contentEditable instead etc.

Comment: put the last character in a span

Comment: @juanRocaminde i need it for the input. I cannot use span and all

Comment: Sorry, you can't really do that. Not with an `input` tag at least.

Comment: The last-typed character? So this character could, at least theoretically, appear in any position within the string within the input element?

Comment: note that it won't work with a space as last letter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with an input tag, unfortunately. We don't have a way to style an individual letter (except for the [first letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)).

However, who says we have to use an input tag? You can display a contenteditable `span` for instance, and feed all the updates into a hidden `input` tag:

```
span.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  input.value = this.textContent;
});
```

Style it with some css to make it look like an input:

```
.awesome-span {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;

  border: 2px inset;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Of course, make the final character is highlighted:

```
span.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  input.value = this.textContent;

  // dirty hack to flatten the tree 
  this.textContent = this.textContent;

  var lastChar = document.createElement('span');
  lastChar.classList.add('highlighted-span');
  lastChar.appendChild(this.firstChild.splitText(this.textContent.length - 1));

  this.appendChild(lastChar);
});
```

And make sure to place cursor at the end:

```
// add to end of event handler
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(this);
range.collapse(false);

var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();


selection.addRange(range);
```

```js
var input = document.getElementsByName('filler-up')[0],
    span = input.previousElementSibling;

span.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  input.value = this.textContent;
  
  // dirty hack to flatten the tree 
  this.textContent = this.textContent;
  
  var lastChar = document.createElement('span');
  lastChar.classList.add('highlighted-span');
  lastChar.appendChild(this.firstChild.splitText(this.textContent.length - 1));
  
  this.appendChild(lastChar);
  
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(this);
  range.collapse(false);
  
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
});
```

```css
.awesome-span {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
  
  border: 2px inset;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
}

.highlighted-span {
  color: red;
}
input {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<span class='awesome-span' contenteditable>blah</span>
<input name='filler-up' />
```

Is this a good solution? Nope. Is this a good idea? Maybe.

Accessibility is not the problem if you hide the input with js. You can embed this into any form and it'll submit as you expect. It's just Not Nice ™.

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo pointed out to you in the comments, the only way you could do something like that is to replace your input with a `contenteditable` thingy.

The idea is to have a `contenteditable` `div` next to your `input` with the `input` hidden. Handle the `keyup` event on this `div` and redirect the text to your `input` so that it the `input` is always updated with the text ready for use in your form or whatever logic.

When you handle the `keyup` event on this `div`, get the last character and wrap it in a `span`. Before doing that, just reset the innerHTML of the `div` to make sure you do not end up with multiple `span`s.

This way you can get the `input` value anytime as it is updated with the div.

Here is a very crude example to give you a head-start. Note that the last character is always red.

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o06L0zaw/***

***Snippet***:

```js
$("#txt + div").on("keyup", function() {
    var text = this.innerText;           // select the text only
    $("#txt").val(text);                 // update the input
    this.innerHTML = text;               // reset the innerHTML
    var initial = text.substring(0, text.length - 1); // get content upto last char
    var last = text.slice(-1);                        // get last char
    var $span = ("<span class='red'>" + last + "</span>"); // wrap last char in span
    $(this).empty().append(initial).append($span);         // append all to empty div
    moveCaret(this);                     // move caret position to end 
});

function moveCaret(elem) {
    range = document.createRange(); // create a range object
    range.selectNodeContents(elem); // select all content
    range.collapse(false);          // collapse until end
    selection = window.getSelection(); // create a selection object
    selection.removeAllRanges();       // remove existing selection
    selection.addRange(range);         // add the range to the selection
  
    // by the time this all completes, the caret is now at the end
}
```

```css
input#txt { display: none; }
#txt + div { border: 1px solid gray; }
.red { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" type="text" />
<div contentEditable="true" ></div>
```