# how to mark last typed letter if it doesn't match with a predefined string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wile typing a text I want to compare it with another one
if typed text is not equal with the beginning part of the another - I need to mark the last typed letter
mark - means change background color or any other way to make it visible different
here is my try - getting error - `last.css is not a function`
for example - try to type - `lorex` - so `x` should be marked

```js
var story = $('#story');
var a = 'lorem';
story.on('input', function(){
    let b = story.text().trim();
    if(!a.startsWith(b)){
        let last = b.slice(-1);
        console.log(last);
        last.css('background', 'orange');  // error line
    }
});
```

```css
.story{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:14px 20px;
    border:none; outline:none;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='story' id='story'></div>
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670758/14559436

Comment: you can't style a textNode, wrap it inside a `span`-tag, where you apply it´s stype

Comment: @wendt88 - can I make a selection of that last letter so force browser to mark it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a small example:

```js
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
span.innerText = last;
story.textContent = b.slice(0, -1);
story.after(span);
```

with jQuery:

```js
story.html(`${b.slice(0, -1)}<span style="background-color: orange;">${last}</span>`)
```